# Is there a reason why my ArcGIS Server token works, when the URL refers to the physical server, but does not work when I use the mapped URL?

Tags: arcgis-server, authentication

http://servername:6080/arcgis/rest/services/xxx/xxx/MapServer?token=xxx

works fine and I am directed to the service information without a need to login

however

when using the mapped (external DNS record) reference, it gets to the ArcGIS REST login page

http://xxx.com.au/arcgis/rest/services/xxx/xxx/MapServer?token=xxx

Comment: What method are you using generate token? Http referrer, IP request or ip? where is the server? AWS, azure, etc... And where are you making the requests from?

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the physical server? if so what do the requests you send look like?  Could it be that the token is stripped off by some firewall or proxy?

Comment: thanks , I think my main issue is that  my public URL http://domain.com/arcgis/admin/ does not work (throws up a 404 error) BUT http://domain.com:6080/arcgis/admin works ok , I can't seem to figure out why it exposes the 6080 port in the URL  token  seems to work ok when using the http://domain.com:6080/arcgis/admin but I need it to work as http://domain.com/arcgis/admin/

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan mentioned in his comment, how and where are you generating your token?

I ran into a similar issue with some REST API scripting. I had generated my token at http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin/generateToken with the Client parameter set to `Request IP`. When I would try and access secured services programmatically using my public URL and token (much like you are doing), I would get an error for invalid token.

What I had to do was generate my token from the REST admin at the public URL (http://domain.com/arcgis/admin/generateToken), using `Request IP`, then my token was valid when used in conjunction with the public URL.

Comment: thanks Chad, I think that would resolve part of my problem. my other issue is that  my public URL http://domain.com/arcgis/admin/ does not work (throws up a 404 error) BUT http://domain.com:6080/arcgis/admin works ok , I can't seem to figure out why it exposes the 6080 port in the URL